# Android: Hide view while scrolling a ViewPager

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a layout with a ViewPager and also right left arrows inside the ViewPager for manually moving to the next view without swiping.
While the user is swiping, I'd like to hide those arrows (or maybe only show the right one when the user is swiping to the right...)

How can I find out if the user is scrolling a ViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Method onPageScrollStateChanged from SimpleOnPageChangeListener

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)

the state argument of onPageScrollStateChanged is 1 when you start draggin, 2 when you let go and 0 when the ViewPager has stopped scrolling

Comment: now the only problem remains how to access a view (the arrows) inside ALL the fragments (or at least the current and the one you are scrolling to) from the activity and hide it...